# I have 3 buttons that can be in either clicked or not-clicked state. How do I keep state that signals if ANY of them are clicked?

Tags: algorithm

This is more of algorithms question. I have 3 buttons:

```
button1    button2     button3
```

They can each be in `clicked` or `not-clicked` state. When the first is clicked, it goes into `clicked` state, but if I click it again, it goes back into `non-clicked` state.

I want to keep a global variable that answers if ANY of the buttons is clicked.

Knowing when to set global variable to `clicked` is pretty easy:

- When I click `button1` I can set variable `clicked` to true.
- When I click `button2` I can set variable `clicked` to true.
- When I click `button3` I can set variable `clicked` to true.

Now the difficult part is to set global variable to `non-clicked`:

- When I click `button1` again it becomes `non-clicked`, but `button2` or `button3` can be still clicked, so I can't just set variable to `non-clicked`.
- When I click `button2` again it becomes `non-clicked`, but `button1` or `button3` can be still clicked, so I can't just set variable to `non-clicked`.
- When I click `button3` again it becomes `non-clicked`, but `button1` or `button2` can be still clicked, so I can't just set variable to `non-clicked`.

It's difficult to keep state of `non-clicked` global status of all buttons.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Should I somehow use `xor`? Or some other logical operation?

Comment: Why do you need to keep this in a variable? Why not just write a function that produces the desired answer when called?

Comment: Even if you do for some reason need to keep the variable, just write a function that produces the desired answer when called and then call it after each state change.

Comment: So that I can resize my window in my app depending on if any of the buttons is clicked or not. If none of the buttons is clicked then I can resize it. If one button is clicked - I can't resize. So I want global variable that tells me are any of buttons clicked.

Comment: @DougMcClean I program without functions though in this project. It's just statements. That's why i need to keep state.

Comment: This is more of puzzle question. :)

Comment: If you really insist on keeping a separate variable you need to re-compute `button1 | button2 | button3` every time that any button is cleared.  And you may have to "synchronize" somehow if there is a chance that the buttons can be changed asynchronously.

Comment: Hmm.................

Comment: I figured out the solution. It's to keep a counter. When a button is clicked I +1 it. When button is closed I -1 it. If counter is 0 then all buttons are non-clicked. If it's >= 1, at least 1 button is clicked.

Comment: What about a | b | c > 0?

Comment: I wouldn't keep it as state at all. You already have the state of the buttons. Just OR them together dynamically when you need to know.

Comment: But I don't have state of EVERY button. I only can change 1 variable when state of ANY 1 OF buttons changes. That's why I need to keep calculator counter incrementor in global variable.

Comment: Hi all. I provided answers to my own question. Please accept! thank you!

Comment: *Why* can you only change one variable? It doesn't make sense. Nor does it make sense not to have the separate button states. At some point you will need to know which button it was.

Comment: And why have you posted the same comment a dozen times? Please delete the duplicates.

Comment: Sorry my Windows 98 computer doesn't work too well with modern websites. Sometimes things get posted many times if I don't reboot the computer. Sorry! Deleted all comments.

Comment: @EJP It's a programming model I invented for my own operating system that I wrote. I can only have 1 global state variable (16 bit) for every window, so I've to pack information in it.

Comment: Hi all. I upvoted everyone's comments. Thanks for helping! Accept my answer as correct please.

Comment: @bodacydo Only you (as the question owner) have the power to accept an answer as correct. You can do so by clicking the gray checkmark next to the answer you want to mark as accepted.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Thanks for letting me know. I upvoted your comment and accepted my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set and clear a different bit in the word per button. That way if the word is non-zero, one or more of the buttons is pressed, and you can detect which one(s) by examining the bits.

Hard to see the point.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out answer to my own question.

The answer is to keep global variable with value 0 in it:

```
int button_counter = 0;
```

When any button is clicked the following operation is performed:

```
button_counter = button_counter + 1;
```

When any button is unclicked the following operation is performed:

```
button_counter = button_counter - 1;
```

Now if value of `button_counter` is `0`, then all buttons are unclicked.

If value of `button_counter` is `1`, `2` or `3`, then either one, two or three buttons are clicked and they are not all unclicked.

Here's how to check if they're all unclicked:

```
if (button_counter == 0) {
   // all buttons are unclicked
}
else {
   // at least 1 button is clicked
}
```

Thank you all for help!

Comment: And how do you know which button was pressed? Hard to see how this provides a usable solution.